# Can a live Linux Mint DVD-R be infected with keylogger/malware?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, malware, livecd

I have burnt a live Linux mint DVD R and I want to use it for online banking.

I am slightly paranoid about keylogger or malware present on Windows 7 though I cannot confirm.
**My question is if my system has malware, can this malware be present on the live disc also?**

If yes, do I have to buy or burn a live disc from a clean system?

thank you.

Comment: You could just check the MD5 sum of the standard cd vs. the one provided on the Mint website.  Assuming you trust them and the md5's match - you are most likely safe.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. Your windows 7 malware will not affect the linux at all, as they are completely different systems. If your live cd is clean you are perfectly safe.

Also it is even safer if the iso you have download is clean and the md5 sum matches what the official website lists. If you are really concerned. you can order a livecd from ubuntu which is quite reputable.

Comment: is it possible to be infected on a live disc use?

Comment: no, live cd is a readonly medium so cannot be infected. it is still possible for you to fetch and run malware in memory if it infects linux, but upon rebooting you are clean again. of course you are still susceptible to phishing, social engineering etc.

Comment: @rajzep - Malware written only to support Windows cannot infect any other operating system.  If your Windows installation is infected, and its not loaded, any infection you might have cannot infect another operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Correction: Yes and No, like other answers, a windows malware is extremely unlikely to infect a linux livecd unless it was specificly designed for that. The only remotely possible way of getting malware on your livecd is if it came that way. To make sure your cd is clean, download it from a reputable source and check the md5 of the image to be sure.

I redact my original post about windows malware as I wasn't thinking about cross system software and forgot it would likely not cross infect. (Opps.)

For more info on this issue, I found a related [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169887/how-can-i-detect-a-keylogger-on-my-system) about ubuntu.

Comment: I used the linux mint website to download the iso file and burnt it using infraburner. Is it possible to scan the disc and see it has any malware?

Comment: The author used a DVDR which can only be written to once.  A piece of Windows malware also cannot run without the Windows operating system.  That does not mean you cannot download a piece of Windows malware, on a device, and by doing infect a non-infected Windows installation

Comment: @rajzep Yes, you can scan a cd. Use either your antivirus or if you choose to install spybot, you can right click on the disk from your "Computer" directory on Win 7. Right click -> Spybot - Search & Destroy -> Scan folder. Keep in mind this can take awhile.

Comment: @Ramhound This is a fair point, but malware can range across systems by infecting boot/BIOS. Very rare, but still possible. Also, most linux systems can wine available which can run windows based software. However, I would have to agree and say that the cross platform transfer would make malware highly unlikely unless it was designed for linux and is on the CD. An md5 check would clear any possibility of this being there should the md5 match the site.

Comment: @TylerScott - The number of malware that infect the BIOS actually in the wild you can count on a single hand.  You would have to specifically install Wine for those concerns, and even then, Wine is guaranteed to allow the malware to run.  Even if it did it would only be in the context of Wine not the Linux operating system.  We don't even know if the author is actually infected, lets not confuse matters, by trying to address every possible situation.

Comment: I would suggest doing an MD5 check of your disk **image** and check to see if it is the same. No malware exists if it matches the site. If the site ever distributed untested images then it would quickly lose popularity as a distro for being untrustworthy.

Comment: thank you for all the answers and suggestions. I will do the MD5 check. I meant to ask if the keylogger can capture strokes from the live session. From what I understand, keyloggers for windows do not work on linux..?

Comment: @rajzep Windows key-loggers cannot log keys on Linux. Only a linux keylogger could log you on linux and to get infected on linux only really happens if you intentionally install one yourself. So basically, you should be completely fine assuming the md5 is correct.